# adicionar quebrar de linhas em notificações Ionic $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule

Tags: ionic

Estou utilizando o plugin `cordova-plugin-local-notifications` e não consigo fazer a quebra de linha no texto da notificação. Tenho o seguinte código::

```
$cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
    id: options.id,
    title: options.title,
    text: options.text,
    icon:"icon",
    data: {
    "type":options.type,
    "value":object
    }
}).then(callback);
```

Alguém sabe como implementar isso?

Comment: Você está no StackOverflow **em Português**, se não traduzir sua pergunta, ela será fechada. | You're in StackOverflow **in Portuguese**, if you don't translate your question, it'll be closed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow em Português!  Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. O idioma oficial usado aqui é o Português, você poderia traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [StackOverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Você tentou "\n" no local onde vc quer quebrar a linha?

Comment: sim, já tentei \n , <br> \n\r

Answer (score 0):

muito obrigado pela ajuda, conseguir resolver.

existe um commit no qual foi corrigido isso no plugin cordova-plugin-local-notifications porém esse commit ainda não está no master. O cara que fez o commit clonou o projeto do plugin com a alteração dele.

então minha solução foi mudar no package.json para apontar para o repositório dele no github por enquanto.

esse é o repositório:
https://github.com/fikri-marhan/cordova-plugin-local-notifications